# how to pass types into test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

**How can I pass types into my unit tests?**

```
public void MethodUnderTest()
{
    try
    {
        var businessService = _businessService.DoWork();
    }
    catch (SomeException exception)
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
    catch (SomeOtherException exception)
    {
        //do other stuff
    }
}


My unit test should be something like this:

[TestCase(typeof(SomeException))]    
[TestCase(typeof(SomeOtherException))]
public void UnitTest(Exception exception)
{
   _businessService.Setup(x=>x.DoWork).Throws.InstanceOf<exception>();
   //verify that when we called DoWork, that the logic inside of one of the catches was executed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be implemented would be, by utilizing inferred generics ..

you will have a test case source in your test fixture.

```
public static List< Exception > Exceptions => new List< Exception >
        {
            new InvalidOperationException(),
            new OverflowException()
        };
```

and then modify your unit test method as :

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof( Exceptions ))]
public void UnitTest<T>( T exception ) where T : Exception, new(){
     _businessService.Setup(x=>x.DoWork).Throws.InstanceOf<T>();
       //verify that when we called DoWork, that the logic inside of one of the catches was executed
    }
```

Then the code would infer the types from the instance of the exceptions in the test case source. I can't think of a way to do this with out instantiating the exceptions ...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you have tried that didn't work. On the surface, it appears easy enough, but perhaps I don't understand what you want to do.

The example unit test you show is incorrect. It takes an Exception as an argument, but you are giving it a Type. Based on your title, the test method should accept a type. Then do something like...

```
[TestCase(typeof(SomeException))]
[TestCase(typeof(SomeOtherException))]
public void UnitTest(Type exceptionType)
{
    Assert.That(()=>_businessService.Setup(x=>x.DoWork),
        Throws.InstanceOf(exceptionType));
}
```

```

Did I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: I don't think your code compiles, you are using exceptionType as a type while it is a variable.

Comment: Right... You can't use the generic here. I changed the code.

Comment: Ah! I wondered how I made that mistake... According to a separate notice I received, it looks like Sam C. added the generic call. I'm afraid I don't entirely grok SO, particularly why folks get to edit other people's answers without leaving a public trail behind. :-(

Comment: No I didn't add the generic call, all I did was changed the formatting for the inline code (so that it reads better). But am glad you updated the answer, that looks like a better solution.

Comment: Odd. I believe you. Strangely though, SO sent me a diff that said you did add it! One bit of evidence that I'm not entirely to blame for not understanding SO. :-)

Comment: You are correct, I believe there is something going on with how SO is showing the diffs, your answer might have messed up with their markup generation engine or something ... so if you go to the link http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39236576/revisions  and click on "side by side" it wouldn't show the changes incorrectly ... but if you click on "side by side markdown" it would show the true difference. I submit this issue to them

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333775/question-revision-diff-not-showing-the-full-difference/333776#333776